# Mixing android's native audio and webaudio

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Since webaudio's decode is extremely long on chromium engine (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424174).

Would it be possible to decode the audio with android's native audio libraries and pass the decoded data to webaudio's buffer?